# Error while saving bot state to azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-blob-storage, nuget-package

i am  trying to save bot framework using C#. I am trying to save bot state to azure blob storage
using nuget package `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Blobs` version 4.19.2.
What i am doing is in Startup.cs file is

```
 var storage = new BlobsStorage(
                "connectionstring",
                "containername"
                );

 var userState = new UserState(storage);
            services.AddSingleton(userState);


var conversationState = new ConversationState(storage);
            services.AddSingleton(conversationState);
```

But i am getting following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the following types in the 'AllowedTypes' collection.
>
> Please provide the 'AllowedTypesSerializationBinder' in the custom 'JsonSerializerSettings' instance, with the list of types to allow.

Example:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    SerializationBinder = new AllowedTypesSerializationBinder(
        new List<Type>
        {
            typeof(PromptOptions),
            typeof(DialogInstance),
            typeof(DialogState),
        }),
}
```

When i check container blob files are generated anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can supply this when you create the BlobsStorage instance:

```cs
    new BlobsStorage(
    "connectionString", "containerName", new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer
            {
                SerializationBinder = new AllowedTypesSerializationBinder(
                    new List<Type>
                    {
                        typeof(DialogInstance),
                        typeof(DialogState),
                    })
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was patched in v4.19.3.